# Android studio Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Another emulator instance is running. Please close it. When No emulator running

Tags: android-studio, android-emulator, qemu

I'm just trying to setup Android studio and my emulator. However I can only ever run it once on pc start up after that if I shut down the emulator and try and launch it again I will get and error and the logs are saying there is another emulator running.

```
2022-07-04 14:18:50,723 [  22398]   WARN -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Another emualtor is still running, wait for a sec... 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,737 [  23412]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Another emulator instance is running. Please close it or run all emulators with -read-only flag. 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,738 [  23413]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Android Studio Chipmunk | 2021.2.1 Patch 1  Build #AI-212.5712.43.2112.8609683 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,738 [  23413]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - JDK: 11.0.12; VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM; Vendor: Oracle Corporation 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,738 [  23413]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - OS: Windows 10 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,738 [  23413]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 -  
2022-07-04 14:18:51,748 [  23423]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Android emulator version 31.2.10.0 (build_id 8420304) (CL:N/A) 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,850 [  23525]   INFO -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Process finished with exit code 1 
2022-07-04 14:18:51,850 [  23525]  ERROR -       Emulator: Pixel 4 API 31 - Emulator terminated with exit code 1 
java.lang.Throwable: Emulator terminated with exit code 1
```

However there are no lock files in the area it directs me to besides `multiinstance.lock.` which I can't delete because it's always in use.

There is no stop option in device manager to stop the device.

Kill-server doesn't make a difference.

Graphics is set to Automatic and can't be changed.

The only thing that fixes it is if I delete the emulator and rebuild it or restart my machine and deleting the emulator gives an error although it does remove it I assume this is because it can't delete `multiinstance.lock.` file.

if anyone can help I would appreciate it.

This is all on windows 11

Edit so I have found the issue, when I shutdown the emulator the process Qemu-system-x86_64.exe under Android studio does not shutdown. I don't know what this does or is but once I end the task I can once again launch the emulator. This is really annoying and I don't know what is causing it.

[image]